# Using DRF Browsable API when Django authentication is OAuth2

Tags: django-rest-framework

My App (Django with Django Rest Framework) uses OAuth2 protocol for authentication.

Note: The package used for authentication is [Python Social Auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and the backend is Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Users are never asked to create passwords!

Not having and **not wanting** password authentication is there any way to provide them access to the browsable API?

In my `settings.py` I define that users must be authenticated:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

In the `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
url(r'^api/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

I'm stuck in authentication because even when users are properly authenticated (in my app) they still have to login in the `/apu/auth/login/` endpoint that asks for a password (which the users don't have).

Comment: please explain your question.......and show some code in order to make us understand it unambiguously....

Comment: @amrit I've edited the question to provide more info. Please let me know if you still find it ambiguous.

Comment: why don't you use rest auth for login,signup,etc...and also you should handle AUTHENTICATION and PERMISSION in ModelViewset....  and in settings you can allow any user like this......'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
)

Comment: I'm not able to do that, do to other requirements. Besides that, I consider your suggestion a bad policy (like putting a firewall to allow all and then block certain ports and ips..)

Comment: .'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',  is for testing purpose only